# Test of significance for glmer

Tags: r, statistical-significance, glmm

I would like to test the effect of a treatment ("crop") on species richness. I would rather use a glm for richness as it is a kind of count data.

Besides, I have a nested sampling design (5 values per plot, 5 plot per treatment). Thus I should use a GLMM.

So I write my model :

```
> GLMM_ric = glmer(richness ~ Crop + (1| Plot),  family=poisson)
> summary(GLMM_ric)

Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) [
 glmerMod]
 Family: poisson ( log )
 Formula: richness ~ Crop + (1 | Plot)
 Data: Com_agg

 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
433.8    446.9   -211.9    423.8       95 

Scaled residuals: 
   Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.33174 -0.41445 -0.08382  0.39853  1.73324 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
  Plot   (Intercept) 0.08432  0.2904  
 Number of obs: 100, groups: Plot, 20

 Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
 (Intercept)   1.9621     0.1503  13.056   <2e-16 ***
 CropM        -0.5351     0.2211  -2.420   0.0155 *  
 CropYR       -0.3814     0.2181  -1.748   0.0804 .  
 CropOR       -0.3393     0.2175  -1.560   0.1188    
 ---
 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

 Correlation of Fixed Effects:
        (Intr) CropM  CropYR
 CropM  -0.678              
 CropYR -0.686  0.467       
 CropOR -0.687  0.468  0.475
```

and then a simpler model to compare with :

```
 > GLMM_ric0 = glmer(richness ~ (1| Plot), data=Com_agg, family=poisson,    glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000)))

 >summary(GLMM_ric0)

 Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) [ glmerMod]
  Family: poisson ( log )
 Formula: richness ~ (1 | Plot)
    Data: Com_agg
 Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e+05))

 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 433.3    438.5   -214.7    429.3       98 

 Scaled residuals: 
 Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
 -1.27211 -0.39830 -0.03309  0.38204  1.66734 

 Random effects:
  Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
  Plot   (Intercept) 0.1251   0.3537  
 Number of obs: 100, groups: Plot, 20

 Fixed effects:
        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
 (Intercept)  1.64739    0.09114   18.07   <2e-16 ***
 ---
 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

And then I compare both models :

```
> anova(GLMM_ric0, GLMM_ric)
Data: Com_agg
Models:
GLMM_ric0: richness ~ (1 | Plot)
GLMM_ric: richness ~ Crop + (1 | Plot)
              Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)
GLMM_ric0  2 433.32 438.53 -214.66   429.32                         
GLMM_ric   5 433.84 446.86 -211.92   423.84 5.4851      3     0.1395
```

So according to my anova, the factor "crop" is not significant. Yet in the summary of my model some of the modalities appear to be significant. How should I interpret this ?

I have looked around for a while (e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9587/glmm-test-of-significance) or [here](http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq)) but I could not find much for this precise situation.